# VBA Array give dimension

Tags: arrays, vba

A question on VBA

If i declare an array variable like

`Dim myArray() as string`

How can i populate the array as two-dimensional when the

`myArray = Array(arglist)`

takes only an arglist that is comma-delimited and the arguments represent one dimension?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use following code:

```
Dim myArray As Variant

myArray = Array(Array("a", "b"), Array("c", "d"))
```

Note, that since `Array` returns `Variant` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/gg264844%28v=office.15%29.aspx)), you should declare your variable `myArray` as `Variant`

Comment: Yes but Array can take string data to.                                Dim myArray() as String                                              myArray = Array("t1","t2")                                           Could you be kind enough to explain me cause your answer bore me a question :P

Comment: Yes, `Array` can take `String` data, but not only `String`. It can take any other data type. You could write e.g. `myArray = Array("t1",123)` and array will contain both `String` and `Integer`. And since array can contain any data, it returns  `Variant` -  a special data type that can contain any kind of data (see [link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251448.aspx)). And since `Array` returns `Variant`, you have to declare `Dim myArray As Variant`

Comment: You the man my friend!!!! Thanks a billion if i can push something to give you reputation please tell :P

Comment: it's all ok! You've already given me reputation accepting answer:)

Answer (score 1):

You could define your array differently than using the Array() function. Working from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from Microsoft, you'd do the following.

```
Dim myArray(5,5) as String
'If you wanted to loop this for example, you could use UBound, as seen in this
'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95b8f22f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
Dim x as Integer, y as Integer
For x = 1 to UBound(myArray,1)
     For y = 1 To UBound(myArray,2)
          myArray(x,y) = "foo" + CStr(x) + CStr(y)
     Next y
Next x
```

Otherwise you could define it normally with something like simoco mentioned

```
Dim myArray(2,2) as String
myArray(1,1) = "a"
myArray(1,2) = "b"
myArray(2,1) = "c"
myArray(2,2) = "d"
```